# how move 3000 image across screen with one button click (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I saw other questions about moving image with javascript and jquery, but I'm working on a web-base real time strategy game and i need move about 3000 image in screen with one button click. which way you suggest that have fast as fast possible speed ? 
if you have sample code, it will be better.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. You want to move a joke number of images to where? The *fastest* code you can get will be raw JavaScript - jQuery will only slow it down.

Comment: clarify your question. but as I could get so far, raw Javascript is your best friend.

Comment: I can say with a certain amount of certainty that the web is not a suitable platform for doing that sort of thing at the moment.

Comment: for more details: i want move about 3000 pictures 20 pixel up,down,right and left with 4 buttons to make viewport of my game. if one side solved 3 others is simple. this game is my final project in university!! lol

Answer (score 0):

don't rely on jquery, it's fast but you need something ultra-fast, just go with a raw js solution,
something ugly but light, as: 
http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/MMTutorial/lMoveImage.htm

you will need to wrap the 3000 (!) images in a container, and just move it...

3000 separated movements are just too much...